# When should Q_OBJECT be used?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

The documentation states that:

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the
>   private section of a class definition
>   that declares its own signals and
>   slots or that uses other services
>   provided by Qt's meta-object system.

But *exactly* what does that mean? On which QObject-derived classes can I safely omit it? Will problems arise if you omit Q_OBJECT on a QObject-derived class, and then inherit from that one? Basically I would like a little more information on when I can omit it from my Qt classes.

Comment: Short answer: You can omit `Q_OBJECT` when you do not need any of the services it offers (signals, slots, meta-object information). If you decide to use the `Q_OBJECT`-macro, it must appear in the private section of a class' definition. This is not a requirement of the macro itself, but rather a consequence of its implementation: Its final expression is `private:`. Also, don't bother reading [liaK's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689807/1889329). Here's a summary: "Yes, I mean, no. Or?"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use the `Q_OBJECT` macro **for any non-templated classes that derive from `QObject`**.

Besides signals and slots, the `Q_OBJECT` macro provides the **meta object information** that is associated with given class.

As stated in [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html):

> we strongly recommend that **all subclasses of QObject use the Q_OBJECT macro** regardless of whether or not they actually use signals, slots, and properties.

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class Class : public QObject {
public:
  Class() {}
};
```

Without `Q_OBJECT`, the following metaobject system features (among others) will not work for `Class`:

1. `qobject_cast<Class>()` - due to missing metadata
2. `QObject::tr()` - due to missing metadata
3. slots and invokables first declared in `Class`, when invoked or looked up by name - none of `QMetaObject` methods will work for these methods, neither will the Qt 4 `connect` - due to missing metadata
4. signals - since `moc` won't generate their implementations and the code won't compile.

You can omit it, of course, but if you ever use these features, you'll need to remember to put the macro into the class's declaration. This is a rather brittle practice and best avoided. The savings are not worth it. So, don't wait - add the `Q_OBJECT` macro to every class that derives from `QObject` as a matter of coding policy.

The `Q_OBJECT` macro should *never* be used on classes that don't derive from `QObject`. To add invokables and properties to such classes, use the `Q_GADGET` macro instead.

Comment: It is worthwhile to note that you MUST put the actual text "Q_OBJECT" in that file, in other words, you can't have a macro that in-turn contains the Q_OBJECT macro, at least not in a separate file, which is the usual case for macros. The meta-object compiler (moc) looks for the text in the classes directly, so it would get confused and try to compile your file that contains the macro instead of the place you are using the macro (which would probably lead to errors at link time).

Comment: Weird. First you claim that using `Q_OBJECT` is **mandatory** for any class deriving from `QObject`, only to move on to quote a section from the documentation that states the opposite (i.e. it is **optional**). Please update your answer to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: `Actually, you have to use Q_OBJECT macro, for any classes that you derive from QObject.` -> That is wrong IMHO, if you do not use signals, slots, properties, qobject_cast and those Q_OBJECT features, just regular QObject things, it is a superfluous overhead.

Comment: Some example code from Qt contradicts the statement `you have to use Q_OBJECT macro, for any classes that you derive from QObject`: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq15-academic.html#connectingtotemplates "If the signals and slots don't require the template parameter to be part of the prototype, the workaround is to make a template class inherit a QObject subclass that provides the required signals and slots" -- this class does **not** use the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @liaK if we are not using qmake but we want to use the slot and or signal system because we have a class that inherits from QObject how can I supplement what the Q_OBJECT macro and lack of using qmake? Do I just call moc on my object or is it a lot more involved?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use signals/slots you MUST include the Q_OBJECT macro and derive the class from QObject.

Otherwise you can leave it out, but it doesn't do any harm to include it in all the Qt gui classes

Comment: `QObject::tr` is not a signals/slots mechanism, but I've just fixed its malfunction in my code due to missing `Q_OBJECT` in the `QObject` derivative that called this method.

Answer (score 4):

Well the first part is pretty clear as you probably already know.. signals and slots, the rest of the Meta-object system is a little lesser known. Perhaps one of the more useful features is dynamic properties. Although these have many uses, I used them to take advantage of Qt's animation system `QPropertyAnimation`.

There's a little more info about the meta-object system here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/metaobjects.html

I think the bottom line is, if you inherit from the QObject hierarchy, throw in the Q_OBJECT macro regardless. It's simple to do and will save you from some potentially baffling problems down the road.

Answer (score 2):

What @liaK said is correct (in short: you **should** always use the Q_OBJECT macro in any class that derives from QObject).

One thing that I haven't seen highlighted is that if you *don't* explicitly put the **Q_OBJECT** macro then using the sometimes **very handy** [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qobject.html#qobject_cast) won't work!!!