# can someone help me modify this code. I'm trying to Display a checkerboard C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and C++. I'm trying to create a checker/chess board where each square is an object. What I'm trying to figure out is how to have each square object be a part of the board object I'm declaring and display that on the screen. I can display a widget on the screen by using MyWidget.show() in the main class. But I want to do something like Board.show() and have all of the square objects that are members of that class(that have a height, width, and color) show up. With the code I tried nothing showed up, although I was able to get a square to show up that was NOT in the board class.

main.cpp

```
#include <qtgui>
#include "square.h"
#include "board.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    //Square square;
    //square.show();
    Board board;
    board.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

board.h and board.cpp

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <QWidget>

class Board : public QWidget
{
public:
    Board();
};

#endif // BOARD_H

#include "board.h"
#include "square.h"

Board::Board()
{
    Square square;
    //square.show();
}
```

square.h and square.cpp**strong text**

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

#include <QWidget>

class Square : public QWidget
{
public:
    Square();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // SQUARE_H

#include "square.h"
#include <QtGui>

Square::Square()
{
    QPalette palette(Square::palette());
    palette.setColor(backgroundRole(), Qt::white);
    setPalette(palette);
}

void Square::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush("#c56c00"));
    painter.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you add your squares to your board?

Comment: why don't you use QGraphicsScene?

Comment: I'm confused. I'm new in qt and c++. modifying the codes will be better for understanding. how do you use QGraphicsScene?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Square` is created as an automatic variable (ie, its lifetime is the scope of the constructor of `Board`).
`show()` will make a widget visible, as long as the event loop can handle the widget, which is not the case here (`square` will be deleted before the event loop).

Also, you [should add the `Q_OBJECT` macro in every class derived from `QObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689714/when-should-q-object-be-used). `Board` is derived from `QWidget`, which is derived from `QObject`.

So, change your class `Board`:

```
class Square;
class Board : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Board();
private:
    Square* square;
};
```

the constructor:

```
Board::Board()
{
    square = new Square();
    square->show();
}
```

and the destructor:

```
Board::~ Board()
{
    delete square;
}
```

Note: for me, having a `Square` class is useless. You can paint a grid in the `paintEvent` of `Board`, it will be faster, consume less memory, and be easier to maintain.

**EDIT**: here is a better method:

```
void Board::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pe)
{
    // Initialization
    unsigned int numCellX = 8, numCellY = 8;
    QRect wRect = rect();
    unsigned int cellSizeX = wRect.width() / numCellX;
    unsigned int cellSizeY = wRect.height() / numCellY;
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    // Draw the background. The whole widget is drawed.
    painter.setBrush(QColor(0,0,0)); //black
    painter.drawRect(wRect);

    // Draw the cells which are of the other color
    // Note: the grid may not fit in the whole rect, because the size of the widget
    // should be a multiple of the size of the cells. If not, a black line at the right
    // and at the bottom may appear.
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255,255,255)); //white
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < numCellY; j++)
        for(unsigned int i = j % 2; i < numCellX; i+=2)
            painter.drawRect(i * cellSizeX, j * cellSizeY, cellSizeX, cellSizeY);
}
```

Comment: God bless. it now shows only a square. and it's not playable. what does the destructor do? and where do I put it?

Comment: You have created only one `Square`... So it is normal that you see only one. My advice is to stop using `Square`, the drawing of the boar can be done entirely in `Board::paintEvent()`. For destructors: see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr380.htm).

Comment: Okay thanks can you create a Board::paintEvent() that paint a checkerboard for me. i'm really finding it difficult

Comment: Yep, I'm writing it. Wait 2 minutes ;)

Comment: God bless you. where do I put it? :D

Comment: Bless you so much. how do I implement it. do I have to get rid of the Square class :D?