# What is the Q_OBJECT for in the following Qt snippet?

Tags: qt

I'm learning some Qt, and came across the following, when trying to implement a model.

```
class Model : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Model(int rows, int columns, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Model();
```

I'm not too sure what the **Q_OBJECT** bit means and what its function is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Qt has extensive documentation, and it's pretty well indexed. Typing your question title in Google brings up the Qt signals & slots doc in the first positions, which will give you a more thorough overview than you can get with a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: And of course there is: [When should Q_OBJECT be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689714/when-should-q-object-be-used)