# How to add slots between child and parent classes?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to connect signals send by buttons in one class with slots of both child and parent classes. Here is an example that reproduces the problem:

ErrorClass.cpp

```
#include "errorclass.h"

ErrorClass::ErrorClass(QPushButton *button) : QObject()
{
    this->button = button;
}
void ErrorClass::makeConnectHappen()
{
    connect(button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(exampleSlot()));
}
//SLOT
void ErrorClass::exampleSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "ExampleSlot was here";
}
```

ErrorClassChild.cpp

```
#include "errorclasschild.h"

ErrorClassChild::ErrorClassChild(QPushButton *button) : ErrorClass(button)
{
    makeConnectHappen();
}
void ErrorClassChild::makeConnectHappen()
{
    ErrorClass::makeConnectHappen();
    connect(button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(exampleChildSlot()));
}
//SLOT
void ErrorClassChild::exampleChildSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "exampleChildSlot was here";
}
```

and finally standard MainWindow.cpp with a QPushButton

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "errorclasschild.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ErrorClassChild ecc(ui->pushButton);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Where `makeConnectHappen()` is a virtual function in ErrorClass.h which is inherited and expanded by ErrorClassChild. I hope this will be clear.

When I compile and run the program there is Apllication Message

```
QObject::connect: No such slot ErrorClass::exampleChildSlot() in ../QListWidgetProblem/errorclasschild.cpp:11
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
```

Now, when I put `exampleChildSlot()`  in the parent as a pure *virtual* slot the error disappears but no `qDebug()` message is shown.

How make the `connect` with parents and children slots at the same time? Or is my idea completaly wrong?

Comment: Do you have `Q_OBJECT` macro in classes headers?

Comment: I have Q_Object macro in the parent class - I thought the child class would inherit it.

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` macro should be used in every class, where you want signals and slots. It's not a property, it is a macro. More details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689714/when-should-q-object-be-used

Comment: @Shf Thanks, adding Q_OBJECT and some minor changes did the trick. If you will put it as an answer I'll accept is as the right one.

Comment: ok, posted answer, glad, that it had helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Q_OBJECT` is not a property, it is a macro, so it is cannot be inherited. So if you would like to use signals-slots in your class (even if it is derived from class, where `Q_OBJECT` already is), you should add it to your class. There already was discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3689807/1741118) , so it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use a virtual slot (the [Qt doc explicitely say they can be virtual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html#slots)) :

Put these declarations in your base class

```
class ErrorClass : public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT
//...   
    void makeConnectHappen();    

public slots:
    virtual void exampleSlot();

}
```

Then, implement `makeConnectHappen()` for the base class exactly the way you did, and you'll only have to reimplement the slot in the derived class. Then, when the button will emit the `pressed()` signal, it will trigger the correct slots depending on the class of the objects you instantiated with this button.