# undefined reference to function send

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a very beginnner at C++ /Qt programming. I've made this simple dialog box that check the QLineEdit, if the text entered is "bob" should enable the OK button.
I can't get it to compile successfully, it gives me:

```
dialog.cpp|31|undefined reference to `Dialogmio::send()'
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is dialog.h:

```
//dialog.h
#ifndef DIALOG_H_INCLUDED
#define DIALOG_H_INCLUDED
#include <QDialog>

class QPushButton;
class QLineEdit;

class Dialogmio : public QWidget


{


public:
Dialogmio(QWidget *parent =0);

signals:
void send ();

public slots:
void recip(QString &text);


private:

QLineEdit *linedit;
QPushButton *buttonOK;


};

#endif
```

This is dialog.cpp:

```
//dialog.cpp
#include <QtGui>

#include "dialog.h"

Dialogmio::Dialogmio(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{

linedit = new QLineEdit();
buttonOK = new QPushButton("OK");
buttonOK->setEnabled(FALSE);


connect( linedit, SIGNAL( textChanged(const QString &) ), this, SLOT( recip(const QString &) ));
connect (this,SIGNAL( send()), this, SLOT( buttonOK->setEnabled(true)) );

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget(linedit);
layout->addWidget(buttonOK);
setLayout(layout);


}

void Dialogmio::recip(QString &text)
{
QString a = linedit->text();
if (a == "bob"){

emit send();   //here it gives me the error

}
}
```

This is main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "dialog.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

Dialogmio *dialog = new Dialogmio;
dialog->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

I've inserted the `Q_OBJECT` macro as suggested, now I get one more errors on line 7:

```
dialog.cpp|7|undefined reference to `vtable for Dialogmio'|
```

Comment: Add `Q_OBJECT` right after the `class Dialogmio: ... {`. You have to add it to whichever class you write that extends from `QObject` to use the signal/slots mechanism. See [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1713) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689714/when-should-q-object-be-used)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've forgotten to mention I use Codeblocks as a IDE

Comment: This is most likely a `Qt` issue. It should have nothing to do with the IDE you're using.

Comment: I'm getting one more error now...about vtable

Comment: Re-run `qmake` and try again.

Comment: `connect (this,SIGNAL( send()), this, SLOT( buttonOK->setEnabled(true)) );` is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start by including the Qt file for QDialog, but then go on to inherit from QWidget. While inheriting from QWidget is not a problem, was your intention to actually inherit from QDialog(?), in which case you should define your class this way: -

```
class Dialogmio : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Dialog(QWidget* parent);

    private slots:
        void aSlotFunction();
}
```

The signals and slots mechanism are C++ extensions that are unique to Qt and in order for a class to use it, the class must include the Q_OBJECT macro, which adds all the necessary functionality. During the build stages, Qt parses the header and creates the code required for  the extensions, including run-time type information, the dynamic property system and of-course the signals and slots.

As you state you're using codeblocks as the IDE, if it doesn't automatically run qmake before building, you'll need to do that whenever you add any signals or slots to a class in order for the moc (meta-object-compiler) to see them.

Another thing is that the call to connect signals and slots is wrong: -

```
connect (this,SIGNAL( send()), this, SLOT( buttonOK->setEnabled(true)) );
```

The parameter in the SLOT macro takes a slot function, so you need to create a slot and connect it to the send signal: -

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(send()), this, SLOT(aSlotFunction());
```

Inside the aSlotFunction, you can then call the set enabled for the button: -

```
void Dialogmio::aSlotFunction()
{
    buttonOK->setEnabled(true);
}
```

If you're using Qt 5, there's an easier syntax of handling the connection: -

```
connect(this, &Dialogmio::send, this, &Dialogmio::aSlotFunction);
```

As this syntax accepts pointers to the functions that will be called, they don't actually have to be declared as slots to work. In addition, you do not provide the arguments, so if they change, you won't have to update the connect calls too.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the code, adding Q_OBJECT macro, running qmake -project and qmake, still I get same errors dialog.cpp|7|undefined reference to `vtable for Dialogmio'| and|undefined reference to `Dialogmio::send()'

Comment: Clean the project, ensure the generated moc and object files are deleted. Then run qmake and build your project. Check that new moc files are generated.

Comment: Thank you all very much! now It works fine. Also Codeblocks wasn't configured properly

Comment: @basicprogram, If you're interested, there's an IDE for `Qt` called `QtCreator` that will help you with `qmake`.