# How to override QObject::findChildren to return only the derived type

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I've found, through answering another question of my own ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869441/why-is-qobject-findchildren-returning-children-with-a-common-base-class?noredirect=1#comment59403163_35869441)), that `QObject::findChildren<T>` will return any child that passes `reinterpret_cast<T>`.

I would like to override the behaviour so that I get only derived types.

This is because I have a composite pattern, where all items are of the same base type, but I'd like to use findChildren to find specific sub-classes.

I tried overriding findChildren as follows:

```
template <class T> 
QList<T> Section::findChildren(QString name)
{
  QList<T> siblings = QObject::findChildren<T>(name);
  QList<T> children;
  for(int i=0; i < siblings.size(); i++)
  {    
    T test = siblings.at(i);
    T child = dynamic_cast<T>(test);
    if(child)
      children << child;
  }
  return children;
}
```

In my example, I have say four items that a children, and two are of one type, two of another, with the same base class. I pass one of the derived types for T and as expected (now) QObject::findChildren gives all four children. But I expect the dynamic_cast to only succeed twice, it does so four times. 
If I pass the returned list of four items outside the template function, I can successfully cull it to the two items I'm looking for.

Comment: Since `QObject::findChildren()` is not virtual, you cannot override it. What you're doing is merely *shadowing* it. Your method will only be called if you're calling it directly on a `Section` object, reference, or pointer.

Comment: That's fine - I'm hitting the code, I know I will only be calling it on a Section. I don't mind it having a slightly different name - but the behaviour is unexpected to me.

Comment: "any child that passes reinterpret_cast" - pretty much all pointers can be cast to any other pointer with that blunt hammer. Feels like something's amiss in your assumptions or the code you've not shown. Could you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Looking at the implementation, QT is using its own wacky implementation to simulate `dynamic_cast<>` not `reinterpret_cast<>`. Maybe you're not using one of the QT macros correctly to setup the metaobject.

Comment: Kurt -you're spot on. I was under the mistaken impression that only the base class needed the Q_OBJECT macro. I delved further and can see that as you say the meta object is used to do its own cast. When I added Q_OBJECT to all the subclasses, I get the behaviour I expect. Thanks all!

Comment: The reason for this behavior is that `qobject_cast` works even if compiler's RTTI has been turned off, e.g. to save space on an embedded system. You **absolutely** need a `Q_OBJECT` macro in every `QObject`-derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The OP figured out that he was using `Q_OBJECT` macro incorrectly in his class hierarchy. I am leaving the original answer he accepted below, but the correct answer is that one must use `Q_OBJECT` macro in base as well as derived classes.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
If `QObject::findObject()` really uses `reinterpret_cast<>`, then all the casts to `T` will succeed even if the type cannot be represented. That makes no sense based on the API description. Assuming you're correct on that point, however, your implementation is flawed because you're getting a list of siblings that are already `T` pointers because of the `reinterpret_cast<>`. Instead you should use `QObject` and then use `dynamic_cast<>` to weed out the instances you want like so:

```
template <class T> 
QList<T> Section::findChildren(QString name)
{
  QList<QObject*> siblings = QObject::findChildren<QObject*>(name);
  QList<T> children;
  for(int i=0; i < siblings.size(); i++)
  {    
    QObject* test = siblings.at(i);
    T child = dynamic_cast<T>(test);
    if(child)
      children << child;
  }
  return children;
}
```

Comment: Although it shouldn't have been necessary - if I had used Q_OBJECT in all subclass definitions I would have seen what I expected.